# How do I save a new path on File

Tags: java

I am making a simple MP3 player and have imported mp3 files from a certain directory. I want to change the path to have double backslashes, however it's not registering.

```
matchingFiles = dir.listFiles(textFilter);
    for(int i = 0; i<matchingFiles.length; i++){
        String s = matchingFiles[i].toString();
        String t = s.replace("\\", "\\\\");

        matchingFiles[i] = new File(t);
        System.out.println(matchingFiles[i]);
        fileList.add(matchingFiles[i]);
    }
```

The print gives single backslashes, while t has double. File.renameTo() didn't seem to work either, so I'm wondering how to change the path in an existing File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File` class aims at representing system paths in its own way, well, the system way. In other words, `File` understands paths as folders seperated  by `\`, not `\\`. You can't change that. The question is, why would you?

Comment: I remembered InputStream causing problems with only one backslash, but that might have been using a String. My program froze trying to load the file into a JLayer player via InputStream, so I thought that would have been the issue, but if File understands \ the error probably lies elsewhere. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Yes, `File` manages filepaths very well. It also takes care of the particularities of your operating system. It has been programmed in a way so that you shouldn't worry about such details.